# Node.js passport sign up

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mobile, passport.js

I am building a mobile only back-end with Node.js utilizing Passport version 0.3.2 for native sign up. The user is being saved to MongoDB properly, but I am having trouble sending back the correct response. Here is my code:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        session: false
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            User.findOne({
                email: email.toLowerCase()
            }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                } else {
                    if (user) {
                        return done(null, false);
                    } else {

                        // Create new user if email does not exist
                        var newUser = new User();

                        // set the user's local credentials
                        newUser.email = email;
                        newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

                        // save the user
                        newUser.save(function(err) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('throwing error: ' + err);
                                throw err;
                            }
                            console.log('the new user: ' + newUser);
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
));
```

Here is my user model class:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose'),
bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    dateRegistered: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now }
});

UserSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

And, I am receiving a 500 response while saving the user, as follows:

the new user:

```
{ __v: 0,
  password: '$2a$08$0GaE32gxf0jdW3vdxDxWeuSjYuwsOzZmHDhrov0ujPgSOl2imoE/C',
  email: 'abcd@gmail.com',
  _id: 58de8e71078555716a76c651,
  dateRegistered: 2017-03-31T17:14:25.407Z }
```

Response

```
POST /signup 500 267.022 ms - -
Error: Failed to serialize user into session
    at pass (/Users/abcd/Developer/node-apps/flow/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:271:19)
    at Authenticator.serializeUser (/Users/abcd/Developer/node-apps/flow/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:289:5)
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/Users/abcd/Developer/node-apps/flow/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:50:29)
    at Strategy.strategy.success (/Users/abcd/Developer/node-apps/flow/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:235:13)
    at verified (/Users/abcd/Developer/node-apps/flow/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:83:10)
    at /Users/abcd/Developer/node-apps/flow/server/config/passport.js:39:40
    at /Users/abcd/Developer/node-apps/flow/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3702:16
    at /Users/abcd/Developer/node-apps/flow/node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/model/applyHooks.js:146:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user id is saved as session data and `deserializeUser` is used to retrieve whole object for future use.`serializeUser` is used to store user id in session. The result of `serializeUser` method store as `req.session.passport.user = {id : 'abcd'}`


On the other side `deserializeUser` gives a object of user on the basis of argument which is key of use means id.

```
// here user id is pass as a id of deserializeUser method to retrieve object
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null,user.id);  
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    customer.findById(id, function (error, user) {
        done(error, user);
    });
});


 <br />
```

```
Add bellow code to your server.js file
```

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
app.use(session({
    secret : "secretkey",
    resave : false,
    saveUninitialized : false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//now add path where your passport authentication file is placed.
require('./customerConfig/passport');
```

Comment: I thought that session: false meant that session data is not being saved, meaning that every authenticated server call would require the proper credentials (email and password in this case).

Comment: If there is a problem regarding session add express-session npm and used as like bellow code i added another answer but you have to add above code to your passport.js file for session handling

Comment: Your implementation didn't seem to work. Still receiving a 500. Any other suggestions? Regarding the passport module, I don't understand why serializing and deserializing a user is necessary when I am trying to authenticate the user with the id and hashed password sent from the client.

Comment: can you please add your route file , where you use passport.authenticate

Comment: And add serializeUser and deserializeUser to your file where you used passport.use function